# JWT::getToken() doesn't get the proper token

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jwt, laravel-middleware

I'm using [JWT-Auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) for authentication. I have created a middleware that checks if token is expired and then it refreshes the token and update the header. But in my controller getToken() does not get the new token but returns the expired one. I have checked the value of header in my controller and it has the new token.

This is how I do it in my middleware:

```
$new_token = JWTAuth::refresh($token);
$request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer '.$new_token);
$response = $next($request);
```

and this is in my controller:

```
$token = JWTAuth::getToken();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at their code. I found a `setToken()` function which solved my issue. I modified my code like this:

```
$new_token = JWTAuth::refresh($token);
JWTAuth::setToken($new_token);
$response = $next($request);
$response->header('Authorization','Bearer '.$new_token);
return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change version of JWT package 5.12 to 5.11 in composer.json file then its work properly.
I was also stuck in same issue before few days

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1198

Comment: It wasn't a version issue